# How to exclude module-info.java in Netbeans (11)?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, java-9

Our source code is still Java 8 complient, but we have two different builds: one built with JDK 11 and `module-info.java`. And one with JDK 8 and without `module-info.java`. With maven, this is easy two accomplish with to different profiles. For the JDK 8 profile, `module-info.java` is excluded:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
      ...
      <excludes>
        <exclude>module-info.java</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

When this project is imported into Netbeans 11 and the correct profile activated, the maven configuration for `excludes` is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Make exclusion a part of base configuration.

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
            ...
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/module-info.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

and override exclusions in java-11 profile

```
<profile>
    <id>java-11</id>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes combine.self="override"/>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I tried your solution. However, i still get an error flagged by Netbeans: "modules are not supported in -source 8 (use -source 9 or higher to enable modules). Which is correct of course. This is the problem: Netbeans does not ignore the file!

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody stumbles upon this issue, I've indicated here why it (probably) doesn't work:

[Migrating maven project to modules - ignore module-info.java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56742016/migrating-maven-project-to-modules-ignore-module-info-java/56766708#56766708)