# Migrating maven project to modules - ignore module-info.java

Tags: java, maven, java-platform-module-system

We're currently migrating to JPMS setting up module-info.java for all modules in a maven multi-module project.

For us it would be ideal to have module-info.java already reside in "dev" branch but not affecting any builds. So idea is to exclude module-info.java by default and include it only in specific maven profiles.

Does that make sense?

Anyway, doesn't work for me, module-info.java is picked up even though in excludes section as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.maven-compiler-plugin}</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
        <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
        <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-Xlint:${maven.compiler.warningsToIgnore}</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/module-info.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Any ideas?

PS: Idea was taken from [How to exclude module-info.java in Netbeans (11)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56670787/how-to-exclude-module-info-java-in-netbeans-11)

Comment: If you use modules it will affect builds cause you are building with Java Modules...and apart from that it does not make sense to ignore them on one side but like to have them on the other side ...either you have modules or you don't ...because they will influence your design, your tests etc.. you possible access to other modules etc. So if you don't like to have them than just remove the module-info from your build otherwise you have it with you...

Comment: I guess you're right, it's probably not worth the hassle to do a migration period as I outlined. We'll just have module-info in the source and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

Still it's intersting that filter doesn't work for module-info.java, but looking the source of compiler plugin I guess that's just the way it is:

https://github.com/apache/maven-compiler-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/compiler/CompilerMojo.java

```
    protected void preparePaths( Set<File> sourceFiles )
    {
        //assert compilePath != null;

        File moduleDescriptorPath = null;

        boolean hasModuleDescriptor = false;
        for ( File sourceFile : sourceFiles )
        {
            if ( "module-info.java".equals( sourceFile.getName() ) )
            {
                moduleDescriptorPath = sourceFile;
                hasModuleDescriptor = true;
                break;
            }
}
```